# Preventing spry validation on hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, hidden-field, spry

I have a form with spry validation applied to some elements.

On this form is also a drop down which hides certain elements depending on what is selected.

Initially the spry validation code was at the bottom of the page, but the form was prevented from being submitted because the form field for the validation no longer exists..
I started off with the following:

```
function checkPageType(myType){
    switch (myType) {
            case 'Standard Page':
            $('.slugDiv').show();
            break;
            case 'Borough Menu':
            $('.slugDiv').hide();
            break;
        case 'Area Menu':
            $('.slugDiv').hide();
        case 'Forms Menu':
            $('.slugDiv').hide();
        break;  
        }
    }   
    $('#idptp_sec').change(function() {
        var myVal = $(this).val();
        checkPageType(myVal);
    });
```

And at the bottom of my page

```
<script type = "text/Javascript">
var slug_sec_Spry = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("slug_sec_Spry", "none",{validateOn:["blur"], characterMasking: /^[a-z0-9-]+$/, useCharacterMasking:true});
</script>
```

I have tried moving this to within my function but it still does not work, am guessing because it only has scope witin the function maybe?

```
function checkPageType(myType){
    switch (myType) {
        case 'Standard Page':
            $('.slugDiv').show();
            var slug_sec_Spry = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("slug_sec_Spry", "none",{validateOn:["blur"], characterMasking: /^[a-z0-9-]+$/, useCharacterMasking:true});
        break;
        case 'Borough Menu':
            $('.slugDiv').hide();
            slug_sec_Spry.destroy();
            slug_sec_Spry= null;
        break;
        case 'Area Menu':
            $('.slugDiv').hide();
            slug_sec_Spry.destroy();
            slug_sec_Spry= null;
        case 'Forms Menu':
            $('.slugDiv').hide();
            slug_sec_Spry.destroy();
            slug_sec_Spry= null;
        break;  
    }
}   
$('#idptp_sec').change(function() {
    var myVal = $(this).val();
    checkPageType(myVal);
});
```

So how can i prevent the field from being validated if its been hidden after the page has loaded?

UPDATE:

I have been trying other soloutions found on here:
[Spry validation prevents the form submission on unavailable fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453556/spry-validation-prevents-the-form-submission-on-unavailable-fields?rq=1)

i have changed my code to:

```
var slug_sec_Spry =  Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("slug_sec_Spry", "none",{validateOn:["blur"],characterMasking: /^[a-z0-9-]+$/, useCharacterMasking:true});

    function clearValidation(){
    if(slug_sec_Spry){
        slug_sec_Spry.reset();
        slug_sec_Spry.destroy()
    }
}

function reapplyValidation(){
    slug_sec_Spry = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("slug_sec_Spry", "none",{validateOn:["blur"],characterMasking: /^[a-z0-9-]+$/, useCharacterMasking:true});
}
    function checkPageType(myType){
        switch (myType) {
            case 'Standard Page':
                $('.slugDiv').show();
                reapplyValidation()
            break;
            case 'Borough Menu':
                $('.slugDiv').hide();
                clearValidation()
            break;
            case 'Area Menu':
                $('.slugDiv').hide();
                clearValidation()
            case 'Forms Menu':
                $('.slugDiv').hide();
                clearValidation()
            break;  
        }
    }   
    $('#idptp_sec').change(function() {
        var myVal = $(this).val();
        checkPageType(myVal);
    });
```

but they generate TypeError: `this.isBrowserSupported is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

working now, just needed some error checing code in there...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var  isHidden = false;

    function clearValidation(){
        slug_sec_Spry.reset();
        slug_sec_Spry.destroy();
        $('.slugDiv').hide();
        isHidden = true;

    }
    function reapplyValidation(){
        $('.slugDiv').show();
        slug_sec_Spry = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("slug_sec_Spry", "none",{validateOn:["blur"], characterMasking: /^[a-z0-9-]+$/, useCharacterMasking:true});
        isHidden = false;
    }
    function checkPageType(myType){
        switch (myType) {
            case 'Standard Page':
                if(isHidden == true){
                    reapplyValidation();
                }

            break;
            case 'Borough Menu':
                if(isHidden == false){
                    clearValidation()
                }
            break;
            case 'Area Menu':     
                if(isHidden == false){
                    clearValidation()
                }
            case 'Forms Menu':
                if(isHidden == false){
                    clearValidation()
                }
            break;  
        }
    }   
    $('#idptp_sec').change(function() {
        var myVal = $(this).val();
        checkPageType(myVal);
    });
    //perform initial check
    var initVal = $('#idptp_sec').val();
    checkPageType(initVal);
});
</script>
```